# How to get RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() from User Attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, routedata

```
    [CheckAccessMethod(RouteData.Values["action"].ToString())]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(){...}

    class CheckAccessMethodAttribute : Attribute
    {
         string MethodName { get; set; }

        public  CheckAccessMethodAttribute(string methodName)
        {
            MethodName = methodName;
        }

    }
```

I can’t get the current request route.
I want to create method access logic for users

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the ActionFilterAttribute, then you'd have access to the ResultExecutingContext which has the route data you need. [More information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
     {
         var action = context.RouteData.Values["action"];
         //do something with action here

         base.OnResultExecuting(context);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.